# Cork-like flavour in "tasteless" Xanthan Gum

Tags: sauce, flavor, thickening, xanthan

I recently discovered xanthan gum and bought a jar to try this amazing thickener for myself. When opening the jar I however noticed a slightly "corked" smell to the powder itself. I made a thick (~5g/1L) mixture with water to see if the taste was noticable, which it was. It was also noticeable in a thinner sweet cherry dessert sauce.

All sources online refer to xanthan gum as being completely tasteless - did I just get a bad batch? For reference, the brand and specific product is [Sosa Pure xantham gum](https://www.sosa.cat/en-ww/goma-xantana-pura-sosa).

Comment: Having never noticed this smell or flavour, I'd try a different  brand.

Comment: I don't do a lot with Xanathan gum, but Gum Arabic gets a boozy, moldy smell when it starts to break down.  So I suspect your gum was too old.

Comment: Have others noticed the same smell? Do you notice the same smell in other batches? Smell receptors are not 100% the same between humans, so you have to exclude the possibility that it is a smell only you can perceive.

Comment: Yes - I've had four others report the same as a sanity check. I am in the process of getting another jar of Xanthan gum, I will report back after trying that.

PS. I would be surprised if this is due to breakdown, as the jar was brand new with an expiry date some time in the next couple of years.

Answer (score -2):

OK to sum up what this is. This can be a multitude of things separate or combined. Since its a cork smell, i would say throw that batch out and get a new one and try it. If its the same thing, then report it on their website (If they have one) and just get a different brand. it might be molding, or staling of the gum. Either that or they make Juicy fruit gum out of the game stuff and its just not reliable. ANYWAYS, i would say get a different brand nonetheless and try that.

Comment: Hi Joseph, I think your point out that this could be due to mold or staleness is reasonable, but you might want to check out [How do I write a good answer?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for some guidance on improving this to meet Q&A expectations.